# Why my viewport based script doesn't add classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I have built a code that should add a class to a div, yet nothing happens. Maybe you could help me troubleshoot. I actually have copied exactly the code from codePen, and on codePen it is working, while on my website it isn't. Maybe it's because I am using WordPress? How can I tell the browser to execute this code?

Here is a link to the file I have worked on:
https://michalkuczek.pl/afsgdtj/

The way it should be working: the second div should fade in when it appears in the view-port.

NEW CODE:

**jQ**

```
<script>
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    jQuery('.anim').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('anima').removeClass('viss')
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.anima span{
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 3s;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: fInUpSmall;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fInUpSmall{
    0%{
        opacity:0;
        transform:translateY(15px)}
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform:translateY(0)}
}

.anima span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
.anima span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .25s;
}.anima span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: .4s;
}.anima span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: .55s;
}.anima span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: .7s;
}.anima span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: .85s;
}
.anima span:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.anima span:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: 1.15s;
}
.anima span:nth-child(9) {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.viss{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="anim">
<span>Set</span> <span>a</span> <span>path</span> <span>and</span> <span>get</span> <br><span class="highlight">to&nbsp;</span><span class="highlight">your&nbsp;</span><span class="highlight">destination&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Comment: Change the `$` for `jQuery`, WordPress jQuery runs in safe mode

Comment: I updated the code, now it works. but the animations flash while playing, I don't know why... Could you help? you can see a working example here: https://michalkuczek.pl/nowa-strona-glowna/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. The right code is in the question, here is just the additional code that gets rid of the flashing.
In order for the flashing to go away you have to use an additional class on the same element(let's name it: viss), add this css to it:

```
.viss{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and then remove it when in viewport using:

.removeClass('viss')

After that everything is smooth and works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

I have updated the code please check snippet. **Make Sure you check the snippet in fullpage.**

```js
function istScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}


$(window).scroll(function(event){
   $('.textbox').each(function () {
        if (istScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.textbox {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
        background:red;
        height:300px;
}
.textbox.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
.anotherdiv {
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
    height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anotherdiv">

</div>
<div class="textbox">

</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the code, can you look at it now?  The animations flash and I don't know why. Here is a link to what I am working on https://michalkuczek.pl/nowa-strona-glowna/

Comment: i checked but not able to find any script similar to this in your current site.